# GeoGraphics Day/Night way off

Tags: graphics, geographics

I've been struggling to figure out the correct `GeoGraphics` options to get the desired results. Here's what I have so far and the results that I'm getting:

```
   g = Show[
   Graphics[{}, ImageSize -> {Automatic, 1000}],
   GeoGraphics[GeoRange -> "World", GeoCenter -> {60, 0}, 
    GeoProjection -> "Orthographic", 
    GeoGridLines -> Quantity[20, "AngularDegrees"], 
    GeoGridLinesStyle -> {AbsoluteThickness[1], 
      AbsoluteThickness[1]},
    GeoBackground -> {"CountryBorders", "Land" -> LightGray, 
      "Ocean" -> White, "Border" -> Black}
    ],
   GeoGraphics[{GeoStyling[Opacity[0.1]], 
     EdgeForm[{Black, AbsoluteThickness[7]}], 
     DayHemisphere[{2020, 01, 01, 15}]}]
   ];
   Magnify[g, 0.5]
```

And here's the result:

[image: orthographically projected map]

Rather than being the expected hemisphere, it's a wacky shape.

Comment: Could you specify what you mean by "the desired results"?

Comment: Off the top of my head my guess is that the "globe" there has no opacity and you're seeing the part of the disk that you'd expect to be occluded as well as the side you expect to see.

Comment: @CarlLange The side where the sun doesn't shine is a circle.

Comment: Do you get the expected results if you use an equirectangular projection?

Comment: @J.M.'sennui Yes, I do.

Comment: LambertAzimuthal projection shows a circle.

Comment: @Jean-Pierre Right! How to make it work for Orthographic?

Comment: Entering the center coordinate in GeoProjection instead of GeoCenter results in a smoother shape: ```GeoProjection -> {"Orthographic", "Centering" ->GeoPosition[{60, 0}]}```.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think what's causing the issue is that the hemisphere polygon boundary is being folded over itself. One such workaround is to triangulate this polygon.

We can convert `DayHemisphere` to `Polygon` by going under the hood with [`` GeoGraphics`GeoEvaluate ``](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/GeoGraphics.html#551258273), and then to a fine union of triangles with `DiscretizeRegion`.

```
tris = DiscretizeRegion[
  GeoGraphics`GeoEvaluate[DayHemisphere[{2020, 01, 01, 15}]], 
  MaxCellMeasure -> 10];

MeshCellCount[tris]
```

> ```
> {4168, 11275, 7108}
> ```

```
p = MeshPrimitives[tris, 2][[All, 1]];

gp = Apply[{Mod[#1, 180, -90], Mod[#2, 360, -180]} &, Reverse[p, {3}], {2}];

GeoGraphics[{GeoStyling[{Red, Opacity[0.5]}],  
  {EdgeForm[], Polygon[GeoPosition[gp]]}, 
  {AbsoluteThickness[7], DayNightTerminator[{2020, 01, 01, 15}]}}, 
  GeoRange -> "World", GeoProjection -> "Orthographic", GeoCenter -> {60, 0}, 
  GeoGridLines -> Quantity[20, "AngularDegrees"], 
  GeoGridLinesStyle -> {AbsoluteThickness[.5], AbsoluteThickness[.5]},
  GeoBackground -> {"CountryBorders", "Land" -> LightGray, "Ocean" -> White, 
   "Border" -> Directive[Black, AbsoluteThickness[.15]]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Very promising. One remaining issue is how to find the triangle edges and, at the same time, show the boundary,

Comment: What do you mean by boundary? That's what the `DayNightTerminator` is for.

Comment: I mean in terms of formatting. How do I make it thick as in my example?

Comment: Ah, I forgot to add that part. See my edit.

Comment: Thanks! For me, the edges disappear only when I do `EdgeForm[Opacity[0]]`

Comment: @Wynne, if you don't want any edges, just do `EdgeForm[]`; translucent stuff is generally harder to render.

Comment: @J.M.'sennui With `EdgeForm[]` the edges still show up